# C++ Vector Memory Leak

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I seem to be getting a small Memory leak from my Vector. I have the vector declared within my Class. Like so:

```
std::vector<int> PolyList;
```

After which I have a function which goes and collect ints and puts it with the Polylist vector and then clears the data. The code is like this:

```
int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < elem.count; i++){
        int j = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            if(k == mesh2->numFaces){
                PolyList.push_back(j);
                break;
            }
            if(elem[k] == i){
                j++;
                k++;
            }
            else {
                PolyList.push_back(j);
            break;
            }
        }

    } 
PolyList.clear();
```

I have this function on a Button Click, and the issue I have is that every time I click on this button, I am losing 4mb of memory (which I know doesn't seem alot, but its a function going to be used all the time). So what can I do to make sure that its doesn't keep leaking memory ? Thanks

Comment: No, no allocation no leak

Comment: `PolyList.clear();` won't clear the memory associated with the vector, only the contents. Look up [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)

Comment: How did you determine there is a memory leak?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I don't see anything that can cause such huge memory loss .  your problem is somewhere else .

Comment: I've just used shrink_to_fit(), still the same. I am using the Windows task Manager Performance to check the memeory. I will check other places now, but its really is only going through that one function, so can't see a memory leak coming from anywhere else.

Comment: @Mekamea: You are missing something then, take a break, clear your head. Sometimes after working long on a bug your brain is so certain of what must be going on that it overlooks details that end up being critical. Have you tried any kind of memory leak detector? (not used to Windows, so cannot recommend any)

Comment: I believe I have found the issue, and you guys were right, had nothing to do with the Vector. It was a bit of the code before it. @MatthieuM. I know that feeling all too well, Thanks for the advice.